# DocuSign Recipient view for a user who acts as 2 recipients on the envelope

Tags: docusignapi

We have a use case where the same user needs to sign as two different recipients on the same Envelope. This seems to be working, more-or-less. See below for the `GET Recipients` response for one of our test envelopes. As you can see, two different recipients have the same `userId` value.

```
{
    "signers": [        
        {
            "signatureInfo": {
                "signatureName": "test",
                "signatureInitials": "T",
                "fontStyle": "freehand575"
            },
            "tabs": {
                "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                        "stampType": "signature",
                        "name": "SignHere",
                        "tabLabel": "Sign Here",
                        "scaleValue": 1,
                        "optional": "false",
                        "documentId": "1",
                        "recipientId": "2",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "xPosition": "191",
                        "yPosition": "123",
                        "anchorString": "@SW1R",
                        "anchorXOffset": "0",
                        "anchorYOffset": "0",
                        "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                        "tabId": "19f2a250-7ffc-4452-b7e2-e0bf1fddd660",
                        "status": "signed"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "creationReason": "sender",
            "isBulkRecipient": "false",
            "identityVerification": {},
            "name": "test",
            "email": "Test@test.com",
            "recipientId": "2",
            "recipientIdGuid": "215d99bb-5c50-4bdd-b298-21639d0aad4c",
            "requireIdLookup": "false",
            "userId": "386ae756-5c1c-480e-abd5-94d960781f5c",
            "clientUserId": "49b09797-cea5-4d87-b653-49f13f733dd3",
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "status": "completed",
            "signedDateTime": "2019-08-02T21:21:53.9570000Z",
            "deliveredDateTime": "2019-08-02T21:16:54.9800000Z",
            "totalTabCount": "4"
        },
        {
            "signatureInfo": {
                "signatureName": "test",
                "signatureInitials": "T",
                "fontStyle": "freehand575"
            },
            "tabs": {
                "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                        "stampType": "signature",
                        "name": "SignHere",
                        "tabLabel": "Sign Here",
                        "scaleValue": 1,
                        "optional": "false",
                        "documentId": "1",
                        "recipientId": "3",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "xPosition": "189",
                        "yPosition": "167",
                        "anchorString": "@SPAAR",
                        "anchorXOffset": "0",
                        "anchorYOffset": "0",
                        "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                        "tabId": "e2def7a9-bfdb-404d-8901-e387d9e4f856"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "creationReason": "sender",
            "isBulkRecipient": "false",
            "identityVerification": {},
            "name": "test",
            "email": "Test@test.com",
            "recipientId": "3",
            "recipientIdGuid": "0b6541f4-45b7-4b6e-a4cb-740d2f9f07a7",
            "requireIdLookup": "false",
            "userId": "386ae756-5c1c-480e-abd5-94d960781f5c",
            "clientUserId": "49b09797-cea5-4d87-b653-49f13f733dd3",
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "status": "delivered",
            "deliveredDateTime": "2019-08-02T20:36:14.5170000Z",
            "totalTabCount": "4"
        }
    ],
    "agents": [],
    "editors": [],
    "intermediaries": [],
    "carbonCopies": [],
    "certifiedDeliveries": [],
    "inPersonSigners": [],
    "seals": [],
    "witnesses": [],
    "recipientCount": "3",
    "currentRoutingOrder": "1"
}
```

Our concern is when we make the `POST EnvelopeViews: createRecipient` call. We have found that this seems to return a recipient view for whichever recipient does not yet have a `completed` status. **Is this dependable/deterministic?** We have tried specifying the *recipientId* in this request, but it does not affect which recipient view we receive. For example, the following request returns the view for Recipient 3 (delivered) instead of Recipient 2 (completed) as requested.

```
{
  "authenticationMethod": "email",
  "email": "Test@test.com",
  "returnUrl": "http://www.google.com",
  "userName": "test",
  "clientUserId": "49b09797-cea5-4d87-b653-49f13f733dd3",
  "recipientId": "2"
}
```

**Update -** More details around the business requirements:
We create an envelope with 2 captive recipients, Presenter and Agent. At the time of envelope creation, we do not know who will sign as the agent, so the initial recipient is a placeholder user. Later in the business flow, we determine who will act as the agent and we call the DocuSign API to update and "swap" the Agent recipient's email, clientUserId, and username to be that of the actual user who will be signing. This is a process which we have been successfully using for years.

We now have a case where the Presenter and Agent could be the same person, but the Presenter must complete their signing before the Agent (same person or someone else) can sign. When they are the same person, following the "swapping" method described above, we still have 2 recipients but the Agent recipient has the same `userId` as the Presenter recipient.

My main concern is regarding whether the `POST EnvelopeViews: createRecipient` method is deterministic because it seems to ignore the `recipientId` parameter. I want to be sure we can reliably do the following:

1. Allow the Presenter user to complete signing.
2. "Swap" the same user in to sign as the Agent.
3. Successfully get a recipient view for the user as the Agent recipient.

Answer (score 0):

what exactly are you trying to do? when a recipient is complete, you still want to create a recipient view for that recipient? even while the same recipient has to still complete this envelope further down the routing order? This is most likely not a supported scenario. I would suggest that if the same exact person needs to act on an envelope more than once, and they completed their first interaction, then the next request would/should take them to the next interaction. It doesn't make sense to do anything else IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've updated my question with more details. Let me know if you still have any questions regarding our use case.

Comment: I think for your scenario you should use "In Person Signer" which is a different type of recipient and that would solve your issue.

Comment: I've looked up "In Person Signer" and it appears to be a feature available through the mobile app. Unfortunately, that is not an option for us because we host our own embedded DocuSign experience. We also have other recipients on these envelopes who *are* known from the time of envelope creation and we would not want them to be dynamically assigned.

Comment: NSouth, this feature is available in all of our apps not just the mobile app. Please let me know if you need additional assistance.

Comment: Inbar, thanks, I would appreciate it if you could point me toward more documentation. The only documentation I found was regarding the mobile apps. I need to know how this would work for our requirements. Some of our requirements include: 1) After each recipient signs, our system must receive a postback to update the signer's status; 2) While all signing is in-person, some recipients must use their own device while another device can be shared amongst a different subset of recipients.

Comment: https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-in-person-signing here is one article about it.  also for the API here is https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/features/recipients where to find information about it.

Comment: Inbar, thank you for the documentation. I'm still not sure this will work for us because all signers in this case are captive recipients without DocuSign accounts, yet the documentation says "The host must be a DocuSign account holder". I have reached out to enterprise support and they have suggested that I do what I've been doing, but try to use a different ClientUserId when the same user signs as a different recipient.

Comment: the host must be, but not the actual signer. That's the notion of "In Person Signer" which is a different person than the host.

Comment: Inbar, in our case all signers are captive recipients, so none of them would be DocuSign account holders.

Comment: I think you are confusing the signer with the host. I'm not saying the signer has to be a DocuSign account holder, that's never the case. the limitation is only for the host if the signer is "in person" using a device that the host controls.